# changing the image based on id on a click event in angular 4

Tags: angular

I am working on a project in angular where I have a list of product images with respective image description, and there is a grey heart icon at the top right of each image if the user will like that image they will click on that heart and the heart will change to another image which is a red heart image, the data is coming from the **`JSON`** and I am applying `*ngFor` to display the product images and their description, and I made a click event but the problem is when I am clicking even one heart of a product image all the heart images are getting changed. PFB the code for that-

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please append a property (something like `isSelected`) to each item of JSON, and display the heart type based on this property (*ngIf). Click event will simply toggle the property (`isSelected = !isSelected` here)

Comment: Where is the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways for achieving it but since you are using Angular there's a thing that you can do is pass the index and do the changes from your TypeScript file, For Example:

```
<!-- Here's your HTML File -->
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of items; index as i">
            <img src="{{ item.img }}" (click)="checkIcon(i)">
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>

// Here's your .ts File
checkIcon(index) {
  // You have the index here and by using it you can change your model data and view
  console.log(index);
}
```

You can also use ngClass or ngStyle properties to change the display itself like background or whatever... Hope this helps...

Comment: You can mark the answer as right if it helped... and you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is on image `click` event change the status of the item.

lets say that you have a item like this.

```
const item = {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Beverie",
    "avatar": "https://robohash.org/nemoquiratione.jpg?size=100x100&set=set1"
}
```

First you have to add a property `liked` or `selected` if it is already not there.

`item['liked']` = false;

You can do this for all of the items in the array in the `constructor` or `ngOnInt` method.

Your html should look like this. When the `liked` property is true `[ngClass]` will add a class name `liked` in to the `img` tag

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let item of data">
   {{item.name}}
   <img [src]="item.avatar" (click)="likeImage(item.id)" [ngClass]="{'liked': item.liked}">
  </div>
</div>
```

What you ahve to do is add some styling based on that css class like this.

```
img.liked {
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
}
```

And the `likeImage(item.id)` method should be like this.

```
public likeImage(id: number): void {
    const likedItem: any = this.data.find((item) => {
      return item.id === id;
    });

    if(likedItem) {
        likedItem.liked = !likedItem.liked;
    }
  }
```

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-like). Take a look.